# Java drum set project

Tags: java, applet

Hello I'm trying to make a java drum kit but my code does not play sound when I click the buttons and I'm not sure why. I have the sound files in the file with the code so i know thats not the problem. Here's my code...

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class FinalProjectst extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private JButton snareButton;
    private JButton hiHatButton;
    private JButton bassButton;
    private JButton cymbalsButton;
    private AudioClip snare;
    private AudioClip hiHat;
    private AudioClip bass;
    private AudioClip cymbals;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        sampleButtons();
        snare = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Snare.wav");
        hiHat = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "HiHat.wav");
        bass = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Kick.wav");
        cymbals = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Crash.wav");
    }

    private void sampleButtons() {
        snareButton = new JButton("Snare");
        hiHatButton = new JButton("Hi Hat");
        bassButton = new JButton("Kick");
        cymbalsButton = new JButton("Cymbals");

        snareButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        hiHatButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        bassButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        cymbalsButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        add(snareButton);
        add(hiHatButton);
        add(bassButton);
        add(cymbalsButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == snareButton)
            snare.play();
        if (e.getSource() == hiHatButton)
            hiHat.play();
        if (e.getSource() == bassButton)
            bass.play();
        if (e.getSource() == cymbalsButton)
            cymbals.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `ButtonListener` defined?

Comment: Try to use `snareButton.addActionListener(this);` and the same for other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of bad things with this Code, but in short I get "file:/tmp/" as return from [getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase()) . So you are pointing for a *.wav file to nothing.

With this Code the first button will play a funny WAV sound of a hours from the web.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class FinalProjectst extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{

    private JButton snareButton;
    private JButton hiHatButton;
    private JButton bassButton;
    private JButton cymbalsButton;
    private AudioClip snare;
    private AudioClip hiHat;
    private AudioClip bass;
    private AudioClip cymbals;

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        sampleButtons();

        try {
            snare = getAudioClip(new URL("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/Media-Convert/Media-Convert_test1_Alaw_Mono_VBR_8SS_16000Hz.wav") ); //getCodeBase(), "Snare.wav");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        hiHat = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "HiHat.wav");
        bass = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Kick.wav");
        cymbals = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "Crash.wav");

    }

    private void sampleButtons()
    {
        snareButton = new JButton("Snare");
        hiHatButton = new JButton("Hi Hat");
        bassButton = new JButton("Kick");
        cymbalsButton = new JButton("Cymbals");

        snareButton.addActionListener(this); //new ButtonListener()
        hiHatButton.addActionListener(this);
        bassButton.addActionListener(this);
        cymbalsButton.addActionListener(this);

        add(snareButton);
        add(hiHatButton);
        add(bassButton);
        add(cymbalsButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == snareButton) {
            snare.play();
            System.out.println(getCodeBase());
        }
        if (e.getSource() == hiHatButton)
            hiHat.play();
        if (e.getSource() == bassButton)
            bass.play();
        if (e.getSource() == cymbalsButton)
            cymbals.play();



    }
}
```

The only reason this works is because I changed the missing ButtonListener() to "this" (you don't need to if you have the class). And now you have a working path to existing URL for the first button. It plays the sound just fine.

I suggest you look for a way to get the accurate URL you need with [getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase()) or some other method.